# Is it possible to embed a hyperlink within :after using only CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
.events-card-form::after {
   content: "Click here."; 
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

I want to make only the word 'here' a clickable link possibly only using CSS, but after researching I assume it isn't possible. If it is truly impossible to do how can I achieve using javascript?

Comment: `window.location = "https://yoururl.com"` in javascript.

Comment: No you cannot..

Comment: Javascript cannot interact with `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements. What are you trying to actually achieve? Can you show a little HTML and maybe some more CSS to explain what problem you are trying to solve?